# xesearch error dealing with itemize (\item)

Tags: xetex, xesearch

I figured out a minimal working example. If `\item good` has the same starting word in the search list, the document doesn't compile.

If I write something like `\item foo`, the document compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xesearch}

\begin{document}
\SearchList{l}{Better}{good job}

\begin{itemize}
\item good
\end{itemize}

happy good job

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.17 \end{itemize}
```

Is there any way to fix the issue? My real file has a lot of itemize environments and I hope to run xesearch on arbitary text outside of the itemize environments.

I'm also happy to know how to debug this error, like what the text looks like after the search and replacement.

Comment: you can try `\AddToHook{env/itemize/begin}{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate0 }`. But on the whole that looks rather fragile and experimental.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your solution works on my production file. Would you explain a bit? Your comment then would be an answer. I've no idea how the problem is caused.

Comment: the search is based on interchar tokens and I disable that. The problem is that the search looks ahead when looking for the second word `job` and expand commands partly. That can break in various places. You can also try to stop the search with `good\vphantom{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xesearch` package provides the commands `\StopSearching` and `\StartSearching`, which you can hook to the `itemize` environment. However, there seems to be a bug with these commands as well, as this leads to an error that the internal macro `\xs@String` is not defined. Defining this somewhere in the code allows for successful compilation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\makeatletter
\def\xs@String{}
\makeatother
\AddToHook{env/itemize/begin}{\StopSearching}
\AddToHook{env/itemize/end}{\StartSearching}
\begin{document}
\SearchList{l}{Better}{good job}
\begin{itemize}
\item good
\end{itemize}
happy good job

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the end hook is actually not necessary, the begin hook restricts the scope of `\StopSearching` to the environment. However, for symmetry I have left it in.

Comment: That's amazing. How do you know \xs@String needs to be fixed? I tried \StopSearching in vain without the \xs@String patch.

Comment: If you use `\StopSearching` without the definition then you get the error `! Undefined control sequence. <XeTeXinterchartoks> \xdef \xs@String {\xs@String`. The last command on the first line in such an error message is the command that is undefined, so here that is `\xs@String`.